# Detect wrong size when reading a 2-dimensional matrix in C

Tags: c, arrays, input

I'm having a bit of problem when reading a matrix from a file in C. My code first reads the size N of the matrix and then allocates memory for a proper integer matrix and reads the elements to be put in it.

If the input file has a matrix with the proper size, everything is ok. But if there is one element less the code won't finish the loop. I tried a test to check if the element isn't a '\n' or an EOF, but it doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void trashout();
int ** alocamatrix(int N);
void readmatrix(int **matrix, int N);
void printmatrix(int **matrix, int N);

int main() {

  int N, **matrix;

  scanf("%d", &N);
  printf("N = %d\n", N);
  if(N > 20 || N < 1){
    printf("ERROR: invalid data\n");
    exit (0);
  }
  trashout();

  matrix = alocamatrix(N);

  readmatrix(matrix, N);
  printmatrix(matrix, N);


  return 0;
}

void trashout(){ 
  char trash = 'a';
  while (trash != '\n' && trash != EOF){
    scanf("%c", &trash);
    if(trash == EOF){
      printf("ERROR: invalid data\n");
      exit (0);
    }
  }
}

int ** alocamatrix(int N){
  int i, **matrix;
  matrix = malloc(N * sizeof(int *));
  for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    matrix[i] = malloc(N * sizeof(int));

  return matrix;
}

void readmatrix(int **matrix, int N){
  int i, j; 
  char garb = 'a';

  for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < N; j++){
      scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);
      if(matrix[i][j] == EOF || matrix[i][j] == '\n' ){
    printf("Dados inválidos\n");
    exit (0);
      }
    }
    trashout(garb);
  }

}

void printmatrix(int **matrix, int N){
  int i, j;
  for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < N; j++){
      printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Below there is two input files, 06_B will work while 07 wont.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByeiEVRxD2mwRFRlcXkwc0traW8/edit?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByeiEVRxD2mweFp6WWx0V2hPT00/edit?usp=sharing

The proper way to run this program is

```
./program < arq06_B.in
```

and

```
./program < arq07.in
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This while loop will continue until it fails to read an integer or i exceeds N.

```
void readmatrix(int **matrix, int N){
    int i, j;             

    i = 0;                                    
    j = 0;                                    
    while ( scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]) == 1) {
        j++;                                  
        if ( j >= N) {    
            j = 0;        
            i++;          
        }                 
        if ( i >= N) {    
            break;        
        }
        if ( feof ( stdin)) {
            break;
        }                 
    }                     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the line

```
scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);
```

is reading ASCII (*e.g.* `42`) as an `int`, and stores it in `matrix[i][j]`.

It doesn't "detect" `EOF` or `\n` as a valid `%d` format, so it doesn't retrieve or store anything at all.

You can check [the return value of `scanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) being less than or equal to zero to detect that it wasn't able to read another integer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Indeed I reading as int.The point is that the values in input may be '0' or a negative integer. So the test you propose wont work, right?

Comment: The return value of `scanf` is not the stuff that's in your file. The return value is how _many_ things it's read into the second parameter. I only say less than or equal to zero because I believe it can be negative depending on the error state.